# How to include "<>" cascading headers

Tags: c++, go, swig

I'm trying to use SWIG to be able to use C++ code as a Go module.
My folders are organized as this:

```
MyLib/
   -go-integration
      -basic_host
           -basic_host.i
           -basic_host_wrap.cxx // gen by SWIG
           -basic_host_wrap.h // gen by SWIG
           -basic_host.go // gen by SWIG
   -MyLib/
      -include/
          -mylib
             -common.hpp
             -inputs.hpp
             -guests.hpp
             -logger.hpp
             - ...
      -src/
         -guests.cpp
         -logger.cpp
         - ...
```

My basic_host.i file:

```
%module(directors="1") basic_host
%{
    #include <atomic>
    #include <map>
    #include <iostream>

    #include "../../MyLib/include/mylib/inputs.hpp"
    #include "../../MyLib/include/mylib/common.hpp"
    #include "../../MyLib/include/mylib/guests.hpp"
%}


%inline %{
 somefunc to export ....
%}

%constant someConstant...
```

Right now what I have been using is:

```
swig -go -cgo -c++ -intgosize 64 .\basic_host.i
go install

In file included from basic_host_wrap.cxx:344:
../../MyLib/include/mylib/common.hpp:6:10: fatal error: mylib/inputs.hpp: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <mylib/inputs.hpp>
      |   
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

My problem is that it seems that I'm unable to import my C++ files as they are importing files with "<>". However on C++ side I've no problem for using those files(the importing is done well).

My import for my go package is needed on `guests.hpp` but it imports `common.hpp` that imports `inputs.hpp` and giving me that error. Maybe there is a way to import direclty by ext dependencies my lib and not giving the relative path but I haven't found it.

This behaviour might be explainable by the fact that SWIG is using gcc/g++ and doesn't know where to find include files but I don't know either how to change/try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was suspecting, SWIG uses gcc and cgo to produce the files and you can add as an environment variable `CGO_CPPFLAGS` that is the path to your include files.

```
$env:CGO_CPPFLAGS="-I D:/Repos/MyLib/MyLib/include"
```

I also tried with the command -I of SWIG like this :

```
swig -go -cgo -c++ -I"D:/Repos/MyLib/MyLib/include" -intgosize 64 .\basic_host.i
```

But it wasn't working direclty.

Comment: That is obvious. The -I only affects SWIG. The error you receive comes from `go`. As an alternative, you can explicit add content to the generate ` basic_host_wrap.cxx` using `%insert("header")` in your interface file and here use the directory where you deploy headers